# Custom Journey Builder Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a custom activity validating and executing in Journey Builder, but i'm having issues capturing the data they are suppose to be sending over through the inArguments.

They have a sample Request here:

```
{
    "inArguments": [
            {
                "emailAddress": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "{{Contact.Default.PhoneNumber}}"
            }
        ],
    "outArguments": [],
    "activityObjectID": "1234abcd-56ef-78gh-90ij-9876klmn5432",
    "journeyId": "1234abcd-56ef-78gh-90ij-9876klmn5432",
    "activityId": "1234abcd-56ef-78gh-90ij-9876klmn5432",
    "definitionInstanceId": "1234abcd-56ef-78gh-90ij-9876klmn5432",
    "activityInstanceId": "1234abcd-56ef-78gh-90ij-9876klmn5432",
    "keyValue": "someContactKeyHere",
    "mode": 0}
```

Although i'm not seeing any values when passed over. Does anyone have experience with the inArgument and what their payload looks like?
(For reference, I'm using a webserver with a php endpoint for a MVP)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the email and phone number values are not stored as Attributes in the location that you have assigned in your data binding.

When you create a Contact, where are you storing the phone number and email address? For example, if you are storing the phone number in an Attribute Set (Data Extension in an Attribute Group) named 'MemberDetails', then your data binding would look like: `{{Contact.Attribute.MemberDetails.Phone}}`

I recommend replacing these strings with `{{Contact.key}}` for testing purposes and check if the Contact Key is passed to your custom activity.